# Can i use SIMPLE HTML DOM PARSER to parse php?

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

Now, i have this `index.html` file then i have transferred the whole content of the it into `index.php` , i'm using this parser http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ to parse the index.html, can i use it too to parse `index.php?`

Comment: It doesn't have any php code.yet..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just a PHP file with a .php ending, you can parse it no problem. The file extension doesn't matter.

If the file actually contains PHP snippets, you will encounter problems, as PHP code has no place in a HTML structure. In that case, you would have to additionally use a tool like the [PHP tokenizer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php) to extract the source code first. But that would really depend on what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

As long as there's no PHP code there (i.e. the file is already processed by the server)